# Emacs 27 scrolling issue

Tags: scrolling

In Emacs 27, in `-nw` mode at least which is what I use, I've found an issue with scrolling.

If you open `emacs` to see two files at once: `emacs -nw -q file1 file2`, and then scroll down the left window with your keyboard (the selected window by default), long enough to make the screen jump, when you scroll back upwards, the right windows will jump as well as if they were trying to move together. The offending behaviour can still be reproduced even if you change `scroll-step` to `1` or whatever.

If you, before doing the scrolling test, go to the other windows, or close and then split again the second window, or just open one file and the split the window to see the other file, the behaviour is correct.

It only happens when you open two files at once and start scrolling around before doing anything else.

Emacs25 hasn't this problem and I haven't test it in Emacs26 because of dependency conflicts.

How to fix it?

Comment: Scrolling is generally handled inside Emacs within `xdisp.c` and other related libraries that update the glass, etc.  This forum primarily focuses on Lisp solutions, but sometimes (rarely) the discussion delves into the C internals.  Your best bet would be to file a formal bug report and be sure to include your recipe needed to reproduce the issue, including, but not limited to your OS, how Emacs was built or where you got it from, etc.  `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: This sounds like a bug (regression), to me. Consider reporting it: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If it's not a bug, Emacs developers will let you know and close the bug report.